# dataweave transformation DateTime : Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: datetime, dataweave

With this command in Dataweave 2.0 :

```
"08:05:30" as DateTime{format: "hh:mm:ss"} as String {format: "hh:mm:ss"}
```

I have this error :

```
Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor
```

How to solve it ?
My whole problem is to transform :

```
"Wed Oct 18 2023 08:05:30 GMT-0000 (GMT)"
```

to

```
"2012-10-11T12:30:40-03:00"
```

I tried :

```
"Wed Oct 18 2023 08:05:30 GMT-0000 (GMT)" as DateTime{format: 'E MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zXX O'} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssO"}
```

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert a string that contains apparently a time to a Date Time plus Time zone type. Because the input misses the date and time zone the transformation will fail.

Instead convert it to a LocalTime (ie a time without a timezone):

```js
"08:05:30" as LocalTime{format: "HH:mm:ss"} as String {format: "HH:mm:ss"}
```

Note that I used `HH` for the 24 hs format. Using `hh` is for the 12 hs am/pm format.

By the way, it is fine if this is just an example but converting to String at the end is just returning a string equal to the input. Not sure if that is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the second question :

```
"Wed Oct 18 2023 08:05:30 GMT-0000 (GMT)" as DateTime{format: 'E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zXX (O)'} as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX"}
```